# Dozens of small messages lead to 1 GB chronicle queue file

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I write utf8 strings to chronicle queue with daily rolling. The default queue file size is 81920 KB. After I write dozens of messages (1 KB each), the file becomes over 1 GB quickly. How can I control the file size?

Answer (score 0):

Chronicle Queue records every message. It is designed on the assumption that disk space is cheap. You can now by 1,000 GB enterprise SSD for a reasonable price.  Some users retain over 100 TB in queues.

You can increase the roll rate to hourly and delete files you don't need. There is a store file listener so you can determine when files roll over.

The file shouldn't be much larger than the data you are storing. If it is can you a test case which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer. I will analyze the file carefully and send the result back later.